# LED intensity on digital pins

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I am using an Arduino UNO.

On any digital/analog pin, if an LED (with resistor) is connected and we use digitalWrite(pin,HIGH) the LED lights up rather dimly.

On the other hand, if we use pinMode(pin,OUTPUT) and then use digitalWrite, the LED lights up to maximum intensity.

I checked that in both cases, the voltage on the pin is 5V. Any explanation for this ? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I am specifically asking the effect of declaring a pin as OUTPUT versus direct use of digitalWrite on the pin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a specific feature of the AVR microcontrollers, where the
same register (`PORTB`, `PORTC` or `PORTD`) is used for controlling both
the output value of the pin and its optional internal pullup resistor.
The command `digitalWrite(pin,HIGH)` sets to 1 the bit of this register
corresponding to the selected pin.

- If the pin is set to `INPUT` (which is the default), the effect of
  `digitalWrite(pin,HIGH)` is to turn on the internal pullup.
- If the pin is set to `OUTPUT`, the same command sets the output to
  `HIGH`.

The internal pullup is about 30 kΩ, which lets flow a very small
current through the LED. You may notice that the voltage at the pin is
5 V if nothing is connected to it, but significantly less when the
LED is connected. Notice also that the preferred way of enabling the
pullup is `pinMode(pin,INPUT_PULLUP)`.